# Visual Studio Code. Как восстановить status bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Экспериментировал с настройками VScode и закрыл нижнюю строку с наименованием языков и т.п.
Помогите восстановить, кто знает.[image: окно VScode]

Comment: view-->appearance-->show status bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

за показ Status Bar отвечает параметр "Workbench › Status Bar: Visible" в параметрах.[image: "Workbench › Status Bar]

Или меню "Вид" - "Внешний вид" - "Показать строку состояния"